# Python matrix represented as (40000,)

Tags: python, numpy, matrix

I have seen and executed a python program where a matrix has been sliced into a column vector using `a[:,j]` and passed into a function. The column vector has dimensions `40000x1`. While tracing the output, I printed the dimensions of `a` in the function and it printed `(40000,)`. In the function, this matrix is multiplied with a matrix `b` of dimensions `1x40000`. I printed the dimensions of the result and it says the result is also `1x40000`. How is this possible? I have read that `a` will be a column vector(obviously) but how can the product generate a `1x40000` matrix? It doesn't satisfy the matrix multiplication rule. I'm using `numpy`.

EDIT:

Code:

```
def update_state(xk, sk, wx, wRec):
    print("Sizes:")
    print(xk.shape)
    print(wx.shape)
    print((xk*wx).shape)
    print((xk * wx + sk * wRec).shape)
    return xk * wx + sk * wRec

def forward_states(X, wx, wRec):
    S = np.zeros((X.shape[0], X.shape[1]+1))
    for k in range(0, X.shape[1]):
        S[:,k+1] = update_state(X[:,k], S[:,k], wx, wRec)
    return S
```

Output:

```
Sizes:
(40000,)
(1, 40000)
(1, 40000)
(1, 40000)
```

Comment: If you provided a couple of lines of example code, that would be great. Knowing which library and function you are referring to would make a difference since they all have slightly different ways of handling these things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming that you are referring to the [`numpy`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-dev/user/quickstart.html) package. There are other array packages available for Python, but that seems to be the most popular one.

`numpy` deals with multidimensional arrays, not matrices. There is a big difference in that a 1D array of N elements can be interpreted as either a Nx1 or a 1xN matrix, depending on how you choose to interpret it.

Another thing to be aware of is that the function [`numpy.multiply`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.11.0/reference/generated/numpy.multiply.html), a.k.a. the `*` operator is not the same as [`numpy.dot`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.11.0/reference/generated/numpy.dot.html), a.k.a the `@` operator. The operations involving `*` you see in your code do element-by element multiplication, not matrix multiplication as you seem to think.

`numpy` provides a number of different mechanisms for mapping elements of arrays with compatible dimensions to each other. The most common way, which is being used in your example, is called [broadcasting](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.11.0/user/basics.broadcasting.html).

Let us apply the information in the link to the operation `kx * wx` in your code. I will use a simplified version of `kx` and `wx` that will make it easier to illustrate the issue at hand:

```
>>> kx = np.arange(10)
>>> kx
array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9])
>>> kx.shape
(10,)

>>> wx = np.arange(10).reshape(1, 10)
>>> wx
array([[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]])
>>> wx.shape
(1, 10)
```

Here is a condensed version of the relevant broadcasting rules:

> When operating on two arrays, NumPy compares their shapes element-wise. It starts with the trailing dimensions, and works its way forward. Two dimensions are compatible when:
>
> 1. they are equal, or
> 2. one of them is 1
>
> ... The size of the resulting array is the maximum size along each dimension of the input arrays.

In your case, a `(N,)` array is multiplied by a `(1,N)` array, resulting in a `(1,N)` array that contains the element-wise product of the inputs:

```
>>> >>> kx*wx
array([[ 0,  1,  4,  9, 16, 25, 36, 49, 64, 81]])
```

This has nothing to do with matrix multiplication. The remaining operations can be analyzed by the same rules.

Comment: Please check the question now. Thanks for the help!

Comment: @Sibi. Nice. I removed my close vote. Updated answer coming soon (although the answer is broadcasting).

Comment: I checked broadcasting from the link you gave but it said the dot product. I didn't get how the dot product of a 40000x1 vector and 1x40000 matrix is also a 1x40000 matrix. Anyway, waiting for your answer!

Comment: @Sibi. Answer updated. You are confusing dot and element-wise products. You are not dealing with dot at any point here.

Answer (score 0):

So `wx` is (1,N), `X` is 2d; `S` is same but with 1 more column.

`X[:,k]` is `xk` is (N,) (1d), so is `sk`

`xk * wx + sk * wRec` is the `(N,)*(1,N) + (N,)*?`;

`(N,)` is automatically expanded to `(1,N)` if needed, so the result of `update_state` is also `(1,N)`.  Assigning that to `S[:,k+1]` should work, again because a `1` dimension can be added at the beginning as needed.

```
In [120]: x=np.zeros((3,4),int)

In [121]: x[:,0]=np.ones((1,3),int)

In [122]: x
Out[122]: 
array([[1, 0, 0, 0],
       [1, 0, 0, 0],
       [1, 0, 0, 0]])
```

An `(N,1)` assigment would give problems:

```
In [123]: x[:,0]=np.ones((3,1),int)
...
ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (3,1) into shape (3)
```

When it comes to broadcasting `(N,)` shape works fine with `(1,N)`, but not with `(N,1)`.

(MATLAB in contrast is always at least 2d, and readily adds dimensions at the end if needed).

Note that I avoid the row or column vector terminology; the shape tuple is clearer.